# Editable DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView when leaving cell value is lost

Tags: c#, devexpress

I enable the editing feature of editing by:

```
v_items.OptionsBehavior.Editable = true;
gv_items.OptionsView.NewItemRowPosition = DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.NewItemRowPosition.Top;
```

Then when running the program I tried to add a new row but when I try to edit the next cell, the previous will reset to blank, backward or forward it is the same, so the row is not being added, and the cells are always reseting, do I need something else or missing some initialization.
or is there any extra step I have to do if I'm not using a data source.
I'm using DevExpress 14.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the GridControl can't work without a datasource. Your cells' values are erased because there is now a datasource bound to your grid to be stored at. If you have added your columns via designer only at your main gridView, it won't work, its only a view

If you don't have already a datasource then add programmatically a simple data table with some columns and assign it as a datasource to your grid. Then you can insert data

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int)); //use your own names and types
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string)); 
        gridControl1.DataSource = dt;
```

Here you can read something similar https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T195251